# JS Regex to PHP Regex Conversion

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I'm trying to convert JS replace regex to the PHP regex equivalent.

Here is my JS:

```
text=text.replace(/@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+=~`\{\[\}\]\|:;<>\/\\\t/g, ' ');
text=text.replace(/\s+-+\s+/g, '.');
text=text.replace(/\s*[,\.\?!;]+\s*/g, '.');
text=text.replace(/\s*\bbut\b\s*/g, '.');
text=text.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
```

Here is my attempt at the PHP equivalent:

```
$text = preg_replace('/@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+=~`\{\[\}\]\|:;<>\/\\\t/', ' ', $text);
$text = preg_replace('/\s+-+\s+/', '.', $text);
$text = preg_replace('/\s*[,\.\?!;]+\s*/', '.', $text);
$text = preg_replace('/\s*\bbut\b\s*/', '.', $text);
$text = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $text);
```

Am I doing this right? Should the regex patterns be the same?

Comment: Why not test if it has the same output?

Comment: The patterns can be the same, but `/@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+=~\`\{\[\}\]\|:;<>\/\\\t/g` feels just wrong. What should it be doing? Please post sample input and expected output.

Comment: I believe you need to replace `/@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+=~\`\{\[\}\]\|:;<>\/\\\t/g` with `/[@#$%^&*()_+=~\`{}\[\]|:;<>\/\\\t]+/g` in JS and use `$text = preg_replace('/[@#$%^&*()_+=~\`{}\[\]|:;<>\/\\\\\t]+/', ' ', $text);` in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are serveral "*flavors*" of Regex. Each of them slightly different, but mostly the same.

I just assume that your Javascript regex is already working, since you're asking for conversion. But it would be really nice to have sample target text.

Here's my conversion of your queries:

```
1. $re = "/@#\\$%\\^&\\*\\(\\)_\\+=~`\\{\\[\\}\\]\\|:;<>\\/\\\\\\t/";
2. $re = "/\\s+-+\\s+/"; 
3. $re = "/\\s*[,\\.\\?!;]+\\s*/";
4. $re = "/\\s*\\bbut\\b\\s*/";
5. $re = "/\\s{2,}/";
```

I used the webpage [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to verify that it worked, and then did a quick PHP script, with target text, to confirm it works.

Here's a Pastebin the script, and its out put: http://pastebin.com/Yy2Zg11Z

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11396668)

Comment: I agree. Sorry for the uncleanliness. Give me 10 min, and I'll update the answer, to better represent an useful answer.

Comment: Relax guys... I've fixed it.. I now only use the link as a reference, as a good tool. I've also converted his regex and confirmed it working.